# Object interface redefinition in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, overloading

Is it possible to redeclare an object with another interface, to provide overloading of the existing methods?

My specific example is using the `EventEmitter` (concretely I'm using the `eventemitter3` package, but it follows all the `NodeJS.EventEmitter` specs).

So I have this file declaring the singleton instance:

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'eventemitter3';

export const instance = new EventEmitter();

// I could do this:
instance.on('event-foo', 'foo-data');
// or this too
instance.on('event-bar', 12345);
```

I want to restrict the methods to provide better typing so I only can specify the *correct* events, because there's no limitation on what kind of parameters I can pass with the defaults types.

What I want to do is provide some extra interface like when you overload a function:

```
const originalInstance = new EventEmitter();

function on('event-foo', data: string): void;
function on('event-bar', data: number): void;
function on(event: string, data: string | number): void {
  originalInstance.on(event, data);
}

// having this you can provide a wrapper like the following:
export const instance = {
  on,
// ...
};
```

But creating a wrapper, creates extra code that I feel unnecessary... so my question is: is there any way to "soft" retype the original object without extra code? Only using types. Something like this:

```
const originalInstance = new EventEmitter();

interface NewDefinitions {
  //...
}

export const instance = originalInstance as NewDefinitions;
```

The problem I found is, you cannot provide overloading definitions inside interfaces, only when creating the function afaik...

Other *hack* I've found is using `declare` like this:

```
declare function on('event-foo', data: string): void;
declare function on('event-bar', data: number): void;

interface NewDefinitions {
  on: typeof on;
  // ...
}

export const instance = (originalInstance as unknown) as NewDefinitions;
```

and that should work... I think... BUT the [documentation says is not correct](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#overloads-and-callbacks).

Any tips here?

Comment: "you cannot provide overloading definitions inside interfaces, only when creating the function afaik..." that's false. You can overload methods in an interface. It is a very common practice. You can find examples of this in lib.d.ts

Comment: @AluanHaddad nice to know, but if you could provide an example/answer on how to do it would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just leaving it here in case anyone comes looking for an answer...

Overloading in interfaces is possible... I was just having a syntax problem...

This is WRONG ↓

```
interface FooBar {
  method: (type: 'foo', data: FooType) => void;
  method: (type: 'bar', data: BarType) => void;
}
```

The problem is, it treats it as an object (?) and  says `method already is declared`

This, is the RIGHT way to write it properly ↓

```
interface FooBar {
  method(type: 'foo', data: FooType): void;
  method(type: 'bar', data: BarType): void;
}
```

Comment: why has to be wrong? the above syntax is totally correct.

Comment: yeah that I´d like to know, and that was the reason of my question here ... But as I explained I get exactly this: `Duplicate identifier 'method'`, so is just a matter of syntax, I guess

Comment: I gave you an answer, but...I don't know if that's what you asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you're asking, but you can define a new interface as follows:

```
interface IFirst {
    readonly foo: string;
    bah: number;
    func(args: Array<any>): number;
}

interface ISecond extends Omit<IFirst, "foo" | "func"> {
    foo: boolean;
    func: (a: number, b: number) => string;
}

const x: ISecond = {
    foo: true,
    bah: 123,
    func: (a, b) => `${a} + ${b} = ${a+b}`
}
```

Comment: Saw it, but the answer I posted just before yours is the correct one. Imagine if you want to have multiple overloads. How many times will you have to extend the original interface >_<